# How to make fast response of open and close between two figures in Matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, response, figure

I have a program in Matlab GUI that has two figures (Satu.fig and Dua.fig) are connected each other by buttons inside. The outline is:
At the first fig, the button is linked to the second fig which will be opened and will be closed for the first fig. I use syntax:

```
function Dua.Callback (hObject, eventdata, handles)
Dua
set(Satu, 'Visible', 'Off');
```

Everytime I press the button to open the second fig, the response is always low to open and it always appears the first fig though it disappears then.

How to make it fast response? And does the background make it low too?

Thank you!